# Merge polygons problems

Tags: merge, arcgis, polygons

I have a group of polygons which I merged to create one large polygon using the editor toolbar. This worked fine but there are still 5 or 6 lines contained within the large polygon. I'm assuming these are contained within the polygon because when I select the polygon the lines are selected too - how can I get rid of these 'rogue' lines, if I merged the polygons how come I have lines now? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You seem to think other people know what program you are running.  You are mistaken.

Comment: You should probably ask on gis.stackexchange.com. If you wanted to do it in Postgis, I would be delighted to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your polygons don't have correct topology, I mean the sharing border is not exactly the same. There is very likely a tiny gap and when you merge your polygons, you see those tiny gaps as line (try zoom to very detail). If this was problem, solution is obvious - you should correct topology of your polygon before merge - you can use topology class with no gaps rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove the lines by:

1) Enter an edit session

2) Selecting the feature

3) Select the "Edit Vertices" tool from the editor toolbar

4) Find the vertices of the rogue lines, select them, and delete them

5) End edit session and save edits

ESRI resource:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m80000003p000000